# How to merge streaming videos

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, offline-caching

I've got mp4 videos on server, length of each video is 5 minutes. I need to merge them into 24h video for displaying using `MediaPlayer` without pausing for buffering the next video. 
Now i've got 2 ideas about it:

1. Just to stream video until it finishes, then recreating media player & setting new url for it. It works, but i got loading delay for new video.
2. Download & save locally the next video while first video is streaming. Not a good solution & maybe i'll got delay when switching from streaming video to downloaded.

Theoretically, i should have a buffer for video & i need to start to fill it when first video is fully buffered, then start to play it & repeat algorithm when it finish. But i haven't found anything about it except [this](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache/issues/59). Maybe there is another way.
Thanks.